# PHP List items in json data in a table

Tags: php, html, json, curl

I am doing some requests using php i am getting this json data from the url i am requesting from and i need to list the name and tag category of each different set of brackets or item out in html  how would i go about this see my code below

```
<?php
    $query = $_POST['query'];


    $cSession = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.spiget.org/v2/search/resources/" + $query);
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    $result = curl_exec($cSession);
    curl_close($cSession);

    $json = json_decode($result);
    foreach ($json['items'] as $data)
    {
        echo "<h3>". $json['name']."</h3>";
        echo "<h4>". $json['tag']."</h3>";
        echo "\n";
        echo "\n";
        echo "\n";
    };?>
```

[JSON DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2jjX.png)

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\request.php on line 7

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\request.php on line 7

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\request.php on line 14
Those are the errors i get when the file is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define in your `json` loop as `$data` so you need to use it in displaying

```
<?php
$query = $_POST['query'];


$cSession = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.spiget.org/v2/search/resources/" + $query);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$result = curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);

$json = json_decode($result);
foreach ($json['items'] as $data)
{
    echo "<h3>". $data['name']."</h3>";
    echo "<h4>". $data['tag']."</h3>";
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
};?>
```

Comment: THANK YOU soooo much this really helped a lot

Comment: @odude102  glad it worked. just added a brief explanation